# Send to client pdf file with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, form-data

i'm developing a web application using javascript and nodejs. 
I have to respond to an ajax post request of the client with pdf file.
Client code is:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/getSlides",
        data:{name,professor},

    }).done(function(data){

        console.log(data);

    });
```

So i want that client side the object `data`contains the pdf or to get pdf reference from `data` object. 
Server side i'm trying to send this as follow:

```
   app.post("/getSlides",function(req,res) {

    name = req.body.name;
    professor = req.body.professor;

    daoQuery.getSlides(name,professor,infoStudent[0].email,function(result){

        var form = new FormData();


          fs.readFile(result[0].slides_path,'application/pdf',function(err,file){

            if(err) throw err;

            form.append("0",file);

            console.log(file);

                res.send(form);

           });


        });


    });
```

Where `daoQuery.getSlides` function returns an array of objects with the fields `.slides_path` that is the path where the pdf is stored on the server.
I choose to use the form-data because it worked on the opposite route (when i upload slides from client to server) but i don't know if it is the right way to work. 
I just need a way to receive pdf from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Well i took a quick look at your code and i think you have missed to mention name and professor as a variables, the data undefined.
i guess, it should be:

```
var name = req.body.name; //variable defined
var professor = req.body.professor; //variable defined


app.post("/getSlides",function(req,res) {

    var name = req.body.name; //variable defined
    var professor = req.body.professor; //variable defined

    daoQuery.getSlides(name,professor,infoStudent[0].email,function(result){

        var form = new FormData();


          fs.readFile(result[0].slides_path,'application/pdf',function(err,file){

            if(err) throw err;

            form.append("0",file);

            console.log(file);

                res.send(form);

           });


        });


    });
```

go thru step by step, hopefully this will help u